# Declaring a category on a subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, subclass, categories

So I want to refactor some code to our existing DataManager code.  The code base is too big and we want to split it into separate files with the Data Access Object pattern.  So what I'd like to do is have a

```
BaseDAO
```

and then have the individual DAOs inherit from that class.  So I have

```
BaseDAO : NSObject

SomeItemDAO : BaseDAO
```

In the

SomeItemDAO.m, I have

```
@implementation SomeItemDAO (DataManager)
```

But I get the warning, "Category is implementing a method which will also be implmeented by its primary class even though it's not the same method name.  I read that if you have something like

```
@interface NSArray (MyCAtegory)
```

you would not get that compiler warning.

If that is the case, how do I do that with my situation?  I cannot do

```
@interface BaseDAO (DataManager)
```

The compiler says that it cannot find interface BaseDAO.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Edited:

```
+ (SomeItemDAO *)sharedInstance {
    static SomeItemDAO *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[SomeItemDAO alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (void)someTestMethod {
    NSLog(@"test method from condition");
}
```

Comment: What method is the compiler telling you the category will implement?

Comment: @rob mayoff I edited my post.  Both of these methods the compiler is complaining about.  sharedInstance and someTestMethod are not defined in DataManager.

Comment: Can you please post your @interface SomeItemDAO (DataManager) and BaseDAO.m implementation?

Comment: @Crystal, Did the below code work for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Either:** implement your,

`@interface SomeItemDAO (DataManager)` in `SomeItemDAO.h` file and

write the following there,

```
@interface SomeItemDAO (DataManager)

+ (SomeItemDAO *)sharedInstance;
- (void)someTestMethod;

@end
```

and remove these method declarations from `SomeItemDAO`,

```
@interface SomeItemDAO : BaseDAO
//remove sharedInstance and someTestMethod from here
@end
```

**Or:** remove it from `@implementation SomeItemDAO (DataManager)`

```
@implementation SomeItemDAO (DataManager)
//remove sharedInstance and someTestMethod from here
@end
```

and add it here,

```
@implementation SomeItemDAO

+ (SomeItemDAO *)sharedInstance {
    static SomeItemDAO *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[SomeItemDAO alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (void)someTestMethod {
    NSLog(@"test method from condition");
}

@end
```

Because your warning message says that ***"Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class"*** Your category `SomeItemDAO (DataManager)` is trying to implement a method which is already declared in its primary class `SomeItemDAO`. So you should remove it from primary class's `@interface` and add it to this category's `@intefrace.` In case you want these methods to be in `@implementation SomeItemDAO`, move these methods from `@implementation SomeItemDAO (DataManager)` and keep it in there.